# Debugging error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which is updating one sheet and after a while I'm getting an error ( 1004). I checked that macro and it shows me that I have an error to another macro, here is the code, could you give me an advice please? Thank you!

```
 Sub HGT()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ChDir "" + Cells.Item(2, "C") + ""
Workbooks.Open filename:="" + Cells.Item(3, "C") + ""
Range("A1:C15").Select
Selection.Copy
'Windows("" + Cells.Item(4, "C") + "").Activate
Windows("hgtinfo.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("HGT.csv").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.Close
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: (a) What do you mean when you say that you get the error "after a while"?  Do you mean the macro "hangs" for a few minutes and then gives the error?  Or do you mean it was working for a few days and now isn't?  Or what?  (b) Which specific line gives the error?  (c) Your code refers to somewhere between 2 (if the initial active workbook is "hgtinfo.xlsm" and cell C3 in Sheet1 of that workbook says "HGT.CSV") and 4 workbooks - how many are actually involved?

Comment: a) the macro its crushing after 30-40 minutes, it should update one time at 5 min; b) Workbooks.Open filename:="" + Cells.Item(3, "C") + "" ( this line has error); c) there is one workbook and one CSV file involved, the Excel is updating from CSV, thank you @YowE3K

Comment: (a) The `Workbooks.Open filename:="" + Cells.Item(3, "C") + ""` line should just be `Workbooks.Open filename:=Cells.Item(3, "C")` - the `+` shouldn't be used as a concatenation operator (you should use `&`) and there is no point in concatenating an empty string before and after a string (that's like adding zero to a number).  But that doesn't explain a 1004 error.  (b) Are you sure that Sheet1!C3 has the value "HGT.csv"?  (c) Considering that you hardcode the value "HGT.csv" later in your code, why don't you try `Workbooks.Open Filename:="HGT.csv"` and see if that works.

Comment: (d) Unless "HGT.csv" is **HUGE**, it shouldn't be taking even 5 minutes to run that code - it should be measurable in seconds.

Comment: b)yes, it has ( its a big table 30 rows by 30 columns starting from A1), d) its not huge, its updating 1 sec at 5min and after 30-40 min its crushing or faster if I'm changing the update time to 1 min for example...I'm gonna try what u said, thank you @YowE3K!

Comment: now I'm testing it with an update on 10 sec ( I'm trying to force it a little bit ), I'll let u know quicly, thx @YowE3K

Comment: The code you showed only runs once.  If you have other code that is calling this, it may be useful to show that code too - it's possible that it is the **other** code that is causing the error, even though the error isn't noticeable until it crashes at the line you mention.

Comment: I've done another macro which was calling this one, first macro I've asigned as a update button to that interval that I've specified earlier, now it is still running, it didn't crush so far in more than 25 min, many many thanks @YowE3K!

Comment: Nothing I suggested would have (as far as I can see) fixed your problem, unless you have other code which is changing workbooks (or if you are manually changing workbooks) and causing `Sheets("Sheet1")` to be referring to some other workbook.  If you included your other code, we might be able to actually resolve the problem, instead of just making it a little less likely to fail.

Comment: hi @YowE3K, I'm not changing manually the workbooks, the VBA has a few big macros ( I haven't done'em ), I can't attach them here, only if you could see the whole workbook you could understand it, since I know there is no way for private messages on this website and I can't upload it here.